# Start ,Pause,Resume, Reset Timer on VBA user Form

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have these 4 buttons on a design form-Start,Pause,Resume Reset buttons.
So far, I was able to star timer from zero, but the code for pause,resume and reset are not working. I am still trying and scratching my head.

The code I got so far is as below. I am trying to implement this code on my design form.

//Button to Start Timer-It is working-CORRECTLY WORKING

```
 Private Sub StartTimer() //OnClick
    Dim StartingTime As Single
    StartingTime = Timer
    Do
    If CM = True Then Exit Sub
    Label6.Caption = Format((Timer - StartingTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
    DoEvents
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

//Button to Pause Timer//OnClick-Paust at the current Time-Not working and the system hangs on clicking this button.

```
Private Sub PauseTimer()
On Error Resume Next
   Application.Wait NOW

End Sub
```

//Button to Resume Timer//OnClick-Resume at the current Time-Not working

```
   Private Sub Resume()
     On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime Now
    Call StartTimer 

    
    End Sub
```

//Button to ResetTimer//OnClick-Not working as it does not reset to zero.

```
Private Sub ResetTimer()

   Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("0:0")

End Sub
```

Can you assist me to modify this code to enable it to run without error?

Comment: `Application.Wait` is pausing executing an application untill the time in parameter after it. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.wait] You have put there 'Now' - but the same time when it's executed now passes and the program waits untill the time will come to the PAST, that will never happen. That's why it hangs. You need to put it Now+ something

Comment: The same with  `Application.OnTime`

Comment: yes, i already saw that reference before, but I wonder how do I pause and resume then upon clicking.

Comment: put there some small gap as 1 sec

Comment: you can also use `Sleep` instead of `Wait` - Put in Declaraions this string `Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As LongPtr)`

Comment: Also recommend this link [https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/pausing-or-delaying-vba-using-wait-sleep-or-a-loop]

Comment: @IvanSTV but I need to specify the time for sleep. I want to do this using button to pause whenever needed.

Comment: you can use any variable as paramenter `Sleep 200` - sleep 200 mSec or you can create variable -for, example "stime" and use `Sleep stime` . P.S. `Application.OnTime Now` needs more parameters you missed  - see [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime]